# Login failed for user. Trying to access a SQL Server Express database

Tags: c#, sql-server, database, authentication

I'm trying to access my SQL Server Express database, but every time I try, I receive this message:

> Login failed for this user.

Here is the code:

```
sqlConnection cs = sqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS; 
   Initial Catalog=MyDatabase#4; Integrated Security=TRUE");
cs.Open();
MessageBox.Show(cs.State.ToString());
cs.Close();
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You didn't specify a user - you are trying to use a trusted connection which uses the account that your executable is run under

Answer (score 5):

Try to write your computer name instead of `.` after "Data Source". For example:

`Data Source=Michael-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyDatabase#4;Integrated Security=True";`

Answer (score 1):

The SQL is not able to authenticate your windows user because it may have no access rights on the database... Try using an administrator account or to use a SQL Server privileged account.

Answer (score 1):

What I sometimes do is get Visual Studio to connect, via the Server Explorer, and then copy and paste the connection string from there.  If you have [SQL Management Studio Express](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Management_Studio#Express_Edition), that will work too.

[image]