# Inserting data into a SQL Server express database

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-express

I am trying to insert customer details into a database. Following is the code which is throwing an `ArgumentException` - how can I handle it?

```
try
{                
    string constring = "DataSource=.\\SQLEXPRESS;"+"Integrated security=true;"+"User Instance=true;"+"AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|Database1.sdf;"+"Initial catalog=Database1";

    using(SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring))
    {
        connection.Open();

        SqlCommand cins = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Customer(cid,cname,mobi)" + "VALUES(@cid , @cname , @mobi)", connection);

        cins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cid", textBox3.Text);
        cins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cname", ncustname.Text);
        cins.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mobi", ncustmno.Text);
        cins.ExecuteNonQuery();

        MessageBox.Show("new customer added");
        ncustpn.Hide();
        Class1.refreshcustomertable(cdgv);
        cdgv.Show();          
    }
}
catch (Exception e1)
{
    MessageBox.Show(e1.ToString());
}
```

Comment: On which line exactly? What is the exception details? Please be more specific?

Comment: SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(constring);  on this line it shows keyword not supported:datasource

Comment: why you have this `"AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|Database1.sdf;"` if you use an SQL Server?

Comment: actually i copied the code from somewhere and replaced the name with my dbname..i dont know exactly so what should i use than?

Comment: try to remove that piece of code, and make a run

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here.

```
string constring = "DataSource=.\\SQLEXPRESS;"+"Integrated security=true;"+"User Instance=true;"+"AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|Database1.sdf;"+"Initial catalog=Database1";
```

Its not **DataSource**, Allow a space in between like **Data Source**

```
string constring = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;"+"Integrated security=true;"+"User Instance=true;"+"AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|Database1.sdf;"+"Initial catalog=Database1";
```

Comment: Try changing User Instance to true and false

Comment: Make sure the database file exists on the path from where you run. If you're debugging, then on your bin/debug folder. And also make sure it contains username, password or not. If yes, then you need to supply username and password, and set Integrated Security = false;

Comment: As @adricadar said, If you're using database from sql server instance, have created a database named database1 within sql server management studio, then the connection string you need is like below

Comment: string cnStr = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated security=true;Initial catalog=Database1";

Answer (score 0):

From @Sayka response you have to use **Data Source**, also you have to remove `"AttachDBFileName=|DataDirectory|Database1.sdf;"` from connection string. [Why?](http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-attachdbfilename/)

You are using a **SQL Server**, that means **you don't care** were is database located on disk, it's **SQL Server** job. You connect to SQL Server through some parameters (`Data Source`, `Initial Catalog`, etc)

```
string constring = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;"+"Integrated security=true;"+"User Instance=true;"+"Initial catalog=Database1";
```

Note: Please make sure [SQL Server service is **running**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12774827/cant-connect-to-localhost-on-sql-server-express-2012) (follow step 1 from answer).

When you check if SQL Server is running, you will see something like this **SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS)** in parentheses you don't have SQLEXPRESS, than you should replace SQLEXPRESS from `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS` with what you find in parentheses. (example: if you find SQL Server (SQLEXPRESS2012) results `Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS2012`)

Comment: Not only you can take data from any of the SQL instances installed on your machine, but can also take it from local sql databases (.sdf, .mdf files) by attaching from a disk path like the above ConnectionString

Comment: @Sayka you are right, but in his case he copied the connection string and replaced with his database name. And i inhereted that he have the `Database1` already attached in SQL Server. And the path that he provided may be wrong.

Comment: I am getting an error which is cannot open "database1" requested by login.The login failed..how can I solve this?

Comment: @VrijSharma try this solution for getting a connection string http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5626335/login-failed-for-user-trying-to-access-a-sql-server-express-database